# Send Email with Attachment (Default Mail Client)

Tags: winforms, attachment

Right now I've been sending email with Microsoft Outlook with attachment in C#. This works great. I just got a request to achieve the same result with **any** email client. Is it possible to do this with a WinForm application? If so, any places for me to research on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at below MSDN article, has nice examples on how to use the namespace/classes

[MailMessage on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx)

On the GUI part, it might be a bit more complex (depending on how good you want to design your GUI :)). You could try to copy MS Outlook or have simple GUI with RichTextArea and couple of TextBox's with big Send button.

[Another article about NET.Mail namespace](http://www.systemnetmail.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can send email with an attachment in winforms using the System.Net.Mail namespace. You'd need to write code to cache the mail if an internet connection can't be made.

**OR**

You can use MAPI, which apparently can have some compatibility issues with .net.

Here's a MAPI interop project that should send email (with attachment) using whatever the default mail client is installed:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SendFileToNET.aspx

Comment: Here's some more clarification. The users want a popup (email message window) to fill in information and sometimes aren't connected (disconnected clients). Outlook queues everything nicely but some users are not using Outlook and although they could be queued within the application when they get back connected they may not be online as they perform there tasks and then exit the application.